# Building a data service in Angular 5

Tags: angular, service

I am trying to build a data service in Angular 5 that reads data from a flat file and passes it to a component for display.  The file sits in ../data-files directory relative to the data service.

The issue is that I am having a hard time verifying that the service is providing the data to the component.  To keep things simple, I tried placing a console.log(data); in the constructor of the component but so far I have been unable to determine what is going on.

Here is my data service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  dataUrl = '../data-files/migrations.json';
  DATA;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};

  getData(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl);
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  };
}
```

And this is what my component looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-mosaic-view',
  templateUrl: './mosaic-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mosaic-view.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  // providers: [DataService]
})
export class MosaicViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
  // @Input() private data: Array<any>;
  data;
  // chart variables go here.
  private chart: any;
  private width: number;
  private height: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    console.log("mosaic-view constructed...");  // does not print anything.
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    this.createChart();
    if(this.data){
      this.updateChart();
    }
  };

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.chart){
      this.updateChart();
    }
  };

  getData(): void {
    this.data = this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    console.log(this.data);  // does not print anything.
  }

  createChart(){
    // creates the mosaic viz, build on d3.treemap()
    // TODO
  };

  updateChart(){
    // updates the viz when the data changes.
    // TODO
  };

}
```

The console.log(...) statements never print even when I place them directly in the constructor.

In my app.component.html file, I have a reference to the selector that looks like this:

```
...
<div id="app-mosaic-view"></div>
...
```

There are no errors displayed in linter or in the console.  I have tried to follow best practices for setting up such a service but something is not right and I cannot tell exactly what.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**  I made some suggested changes and now I'm stuck with a 404 error for the data file that I am trying to load.  I checked the path, and even tried explicitly specifying the path to no avail.  Any idea why it wouldn't find the file?

New Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mosaic-view',
  templateUrl: './mosaic-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mosaic-view.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  // providers: [DataService]
})
export class MosaicViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
  componentName: string = 'Mosaic View';
  private data: any[];
  private errorMessage: string;

  // chart variables go here.
  private chart: any;
  private width: number;
  private height: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    console.log("mosaic-view constructed...");
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    if(this.data){
      this.updateChart();
    }
  };

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.chart){
      this.updateChart();
    }
  };

  getData(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      (data: any[]) => {
        // this.data = data;
        this.data = data;
        this.createChart(data);
      },
      (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  createChart(data){
    // creates the mosaic viz, build on d3.treemap()
    // TODO
  };

  updateChart(){
    // updates the viz when the data changes.
    // TODO
  };

}
```

New Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  dataUrl: string = '../consolidated_cohorts/src/app/data-files/migrations.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("data service called...")
    this.getData();
  };


  getData(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.dataUrl)
                    .pipe(
                      tap(data => console.log(data)),
                      // catchError(this.handleError)  // TODO
                    );
  };

  // private handleError: {
  //   console.log("there was an error.");
  // }
}
```

404 Error:
    http://localhost:4200/data-files/migrations.json 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the subscribe. The Observable won't execute until it is subscribed to. And any code you want to execute *after* the data is obtained needs to go into the subscribe method's callback.

My code looks like this:

**Component**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
        (products: IProduct[]) => {
            this.products = products;
            this.filterComponent.listFilter =
                this.productParameterService.filterBy;
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

I pass a function to the subscribe method that stores the returned products in a local variable (that I use for binding) and I filter the list based on any previously retained filter setting. (This is just an example from my code ... you will have different code in your callback.)

Your code may look something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createChart();
    this.getData().subscribe(data => this.updateChart());
  };
```

And Yes! As Narm mentioned there is no OnInit lifecycle hook in a service. This is what my service looks like:

**Service**

```
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl)
                    .pipe(
                        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
                        catchError(this.handleError)
                    );
}
```

You can shorten this to:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl);
}
```

I added the `tap` operator to log the result to the console for debugging purposes. And it is "best practice" to add some exception handling.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the use of tap() and my IDE is saying it's an unknown function.  Can you elaborate a bit on how to incorporate tap()?

Comment: Re: my edit above - the reason why the request returned 404 was that I failed to declare the file location as an 'asset' in .angular-cli.json.  When I declared it the error resolved itself.

Answer (score 2):

Lifecycle hooks, like ngOnInit() work with directives and components. They do not work with other types, like a service. In your service you should remove ngOnInit and move the logic from it into your constructor like  as shown below below:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   this.getData();
 };
```

Comment: This is in addition to what DeborahK mentioned about needing to subscribe to the observable in your component. Sorry I would have added it as a comment to her post, but I don't have enough reputation points for that.

Comment: Good catch! Yes ... this too!